# Hard to translate English to Chinese language in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, font-recommendation

I was trying to translate texts on my design into Chinese but for some reason it displays random numbers and letters. Is there a way to get this done? And is there a font that is downloadable to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Why down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found an answer.

I tried the `nSimsum` font built in Photoshop and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Yep.  You can't represent a language unless you have a font for the language loaded.  **This is also true for the other people who will view your work: THEY must have an appropriate font loaded, too.**  Anyone who doesn't will get those little boxes with the unicode indexes instead of the glyphs of the language.

Comment: except in the case of a rasterized text in an image created in photoshop

Comment: aaa, y'got me.  Rasterising it does indeed obviate the need for the font itself.  Makes it hard to use, though.

Comment: @MMacD, Yeah! but I think the `nSimsum` font is included in PS default fonts. But it depends on the font I used if the viewers don't have the font I used it displays weird boxes. Thanks!